# Disable all constraints besides uniques

Tags: postgresql

What is the query to `disable` all `constraints` like `foreign keys`, `primary keys` **but leave `uniques`**?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not allow to disable constraints generally speaking. You can only disable foreign key constraints by disabling the related trigger used to implement the foreign keys.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES

> DISABLE/ENABLE [ REPLICA | ALWAYS ] TRIGGER
>
> One can disable or enable a single trigger specified by name, or all
> triggers on the table, or only user triggers (this option excludes
> internally generated constraint triggers such as those that are used
> to implement foreign key constraints or deferrable uniqueness and
> exclusion constraints). Disabling or enabling internally generated
> constraint triggers requires superuser privileges; it should be done
> with caution since of course the integrity of the constraint cannot be
> guaranteed if the triggers are not executed.